# How to get the index in a primefaces dataList?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

some one can tell me pliz how can i get index (i) `datalist`?

ex : `Bean.myList.get(i)` for putting it into a slide like :

```
 <p:dataList value="#{Bean.myList}" var="objet">
    <slide :index="i" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what documentation you've checked, but please note that the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datalist/basic.xhtml) is not [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datalist). In the documentation you'll find that you can use the `rowIndexVar` attribute with DataLists. It reads:

> Name of the iterator to refer each row index.